# XmlDocument loops through too many times

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML document with multiple faultIsolationProcedures that I need to increment the ID numbers. The code works EXCEPT it count's each faultIsolationProcedure 3 times. I've tried using different XPath expressions and I keep getting the weird 3 time loop.

Code:

```vb
Dim fiCount = 1
Dim renumNodes As XmlNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure")

For Each fi In renumNodes
    Dim origFiId = renumNodes.Attributes("id").Value
    Dim newFIID = "f" + fiCount.ToString
    renumNodes.Attributes(0).Value = modExistID
    dictionaryRenumberID.Add(origFiId, newFIID)

    fiCount = fiCount + 1
Next
```

Example XML with single fault

```xml
<content>
  <faultIsolation>
    <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId="test" id="-1">
      <isolationStep id="i1-001">
        <isolationStepQuestion></isolationStepQuestion>
        <isolationStepAnswer>
          <yesNoAnswer>
            <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="s1-003" />
            <noAnswer nextActionRefId="e1-002" />
          </yesNoAnswer>
        </isolationStepAnswer>
      </isolationStep>
      <isolationProcedureEnd id="e1-002">
      </isolationProcedureEnd>
      <isolationStep id="i1-001a">
      </isolationStep>
      <isolationProcedureEnd id="e1-007">
      </isolationProcedureEnd>
    </faultIsolationProcedure>
  </faultIsolation>
</content>
```

Comment: Set option strict on. You may find something!

Comment: Did you intend `renumNodes.Attributes("id").Value` or should it be `fi.Attributes("id").Value`?

Comment: I changed it to fi.Attributes("id").Value but now get an error "Option Strict on disallows late binding" @AndrewMorton

Comment: @JenPann The loop needs to be `For Each fi As XmlNode In renumNodes`.

Comment: I now get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At the Dim origFild = fi.Attribute("id").value @AndrewMorton

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to change it to For Each node As XmlNode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("/dmodule/content/faultIsolation/faultIsolationProcedure")

Answer (score 1):

Using XElement which I find easier.  First the data

```vb
Dim xe As XElement
' xe=XElement.Load("path here")
'for testing use a literal
xe = <content>
         <faultIsolation>
             <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId="test" id="-1">
                 <isolationStep id="i1-001">
                     <isolationStepQuestion></isolationStepQuestion>
                     <isolationStepAnswer>
                         <yesNoAnswer>
                             <yesAnswer nextActionRefId="s1-003"/>
                             <noAnswer nextActionRefId="e1-002"/>
                         </yesNoAnswer>
                     </isolationStepAnswer>
                 </isolationStep>
                 <isolationProcedureEnd id="e1-002">
                 </isolationProcedureEnd>
                 <isolationStep id="i1-001a">
                 </isolationStep>
                 <isolationProcedureEnd id="e1-007">
                 </isolationProcedureEnd>
             </faultIsolationProcedure>
             <faultIsolationProcedure applicRefId="test" id="">
                 <isolationProcedureEnd id="e1-007">
                 </isolationProcedureEnd>
             </faultIsolationProcedure>
         </faultIsolation>
     </content>
```

Notice that I added one faultIsolationProcedure.

Then using that data the id can be incremented like this

```vb
Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

'get all faultIsolationProcedure
ie = From el In xe...<faultIsolationProcedure> Select el

'increment id
For Each f As XElement In ie
    Dim idv As Integer = 0
    If Integer.TryParse(f.@id, idv) Then
        f.@id = (idv + 1).ToString
    Else
        Dim att As XAttribute = f.Attribute("id")
        If att IsNot Nothing Then
            f.@id = "1"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Wow that looks really confusing to me. Let me sit on it a bit hopefully I'll understand more. Thank you for the detailed response

Comment: @JenPann - here is a link to XML LINQ  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml

Comment: @JenPann if you use the debugger and step through the code....